# Minio client connection error java spring framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, minio

//config
MinioClient minioClient = MinioClient.builder().endpoint(minioEndpoint).credentials(accessKey, accessSecret).build();

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at MinioServiceImpl.getAllBuckets(MinioServiceImpl.java)

Comment: are you connecting to minio over https and is the certificate valid? The error may come from the call to minioClient.build(), but is caused because of certificate issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need check on server certificate for HTTPS connection you can ignore it.

```
minioClient.ignoreCertCheck();
```

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem myself. You need to change the minio endpoint.

miniEndpoint = https://minio-api.example.com/

to

miniEnpoint = http://12.34.56.78:9001/

it fixed when i did it like this. reason is using port 443 not port 9001.